# How to connect to a server without the port number in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, client-server

I am trying to make a "universal client" that can connect to any server given the IP Address. I was wondering if there is a way to find the port number. I have tried using a for loop inside a while(true). The for loop would terminate at 65535, the highest possible port number. Each time it would loop through the for loop it would create a new Socket with the ip address and the port number it is testing for.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class MainClass {

static String serverIp = "127.0.0.1"; // or what ever ip the server is on


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        while (true) {
            for (int x = 1; x == 65535; x++) {                  
                Socket serverTest = new Socket(
                        InetAddress.getByName(serverIp), x);
                if(serverTest.isConnected()){
                    connect(serverTest.getPort());
                }

            }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void connect(int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    Socket serverTest = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIp), port);      
}
```

}

Comment: The `isConnected()` test is futile. If it wasn't connected it wouldn't have been constructed: that constructor would have thrown an `IOException` of some kind.

Comment: i think this is not a good method .if u are working in Linux then using some commands you can find via which port you are connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that much about Socket but I can tell you there is definitely a problem with your `for` loop:

```
for (int x = 1; x == 65535; x++)
```

Remember that a `for` loop just expands like a `while` loop, so this translates to the following:

```
int x = 1;
while (x == 65535) {
    // ...
    x++;
}
```

You can probably see what is going on now. (The loop is never executed.) It seems like you intended this:

```
//                v
for (int x = 1; x <= 65535; x++)
```